# Is there an up-to-date and viable rust implementation of Bitcoin?

Tags: implementation

I saw 2 rust implementations of Bitcoin.

Parity Bitcoin: https://github.com/paritytech/parity-bitcoin

Rust-Bitcoin: https://github.com/apoelstra/rust-bitcoin

They are not updated for some time now.
Are there any other up-to-date and viable rust implementations?

Comment: https://github.com/rust-bitcoin/rust-bitcoin looks actively developed.

Comment: Parity bitcoin has last commit on Aug 24, 2020. 
Rust bitcoin has last commit on Oct 12, 2018.    I believe there are changes in Bitcoin after that right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking at but (a) rust-bitcoin had a commit (and a release!) yesterday and (b) "changes in Bitcoin" isn't very well-defined; in general, just because some changes are implemented in one piece of software doesn't mean they need to be incorporated everywhere. Almost everything is opt-in, so if you don't make use of a feature, you generally don't care about it (this is true for consensus changes, p2p protocol changes, wallet standards, ...).

Comment: Oh, you're looking at apoelstra's fork whose master branch is outdated. That's not the right place to look; use the project repository https://github.com/rust-bitcoin/rust-bitcoin

Comment: This should probably be in https://github.com/igorbarinov/awesome-bitcoin or https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Software rather than here.